# Solved; See Edit5; Running a "For Each" Loop in Visual Basic "Space Invaders" Game seems to slowdown everything else

Tags: vb.net

[Solved] See Edit5

I'm trying to make a "Space Invaders" game for a class and every time I turn on the timer handling the enemies the player movement slows down immensely. I'm almost sure the issue, or at least the bulk of it, comes from this loop:

```
For Each PicBox2 In EnemyList
            If Not ((PicBox2.Left + EMovDir * ESpeed < 0) Or (PicBox2.Right + EMovDir * ESpeed >= Me.Width - 10)) Then
                PicBox2.Location = New Point(PicBox2.Location.X + EMovDir * ESpeed, PicBox2.Location.Y)
                If PicBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Player.Bounds) Then GameOver = True
            End If
        Next

Here is a screenshot of the form design:
[enter image description here][1]

And here is the code I have so far:

    Public Class Form1

Region Variables

    Dim PSpeed As Integer = 5 'Pixeis de movimento do jogador por trigger do EventoKeyDown
    Dim ESpeed As Integer = 10    'Pixeis de movimento dos inimigos por loop
    Dim ENumber As Integer   'Número de inimigos 
    Dim PHealth As Integer    'Número de vezes que o jogador pode ser atingdo até GameOver
    Dim PMoveStateL As Boolean
    Dim PMoveStateR As Boolean
    Dim GameOver As Boolean
    Dim EMovDir As Integer = 1
    Dim PicBox As PictureBox
    Dim EnemyList As New List(Of PictureBox)

End Region


Region Game Load


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For Each PicBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)
            If PicBox.Tag = "Enemy" Then
                EnemyList.Add(PicBox)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


End Region


Region InGame Ui

    Private Sub StopStartTimer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If EnemyTimer.Enabled = False Then
            EnemyTimer.Enabled = True
        Else EnemyTimer.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub


End Region

Region PlayerControls

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown           'Não Esquecer de ativar a Propriedade KeyPreview
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.D And (Player.Location.X + PSpeed) < (Me.Width - Player.Width) Then
            PMoveStateR = True

        End If

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A And ((Player.Location.X - PSpeed) > 0) Then
            PMoveStateL = True

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
            PMoveStateR = False

        End If

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
            PMoveStateL = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PlayerTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayerTimer.Tick

        If PMoveStateR = True And (Player.Location.X + PSpeed) < (Me.Width - Player.Width) Then
            Player.Location = New Point((Player.Location.X + PSpeed), Player.Location.Y)

        End If

        If PMoveStateL = True And ((Player.Location.X - PSpeed) > 0) Then
            Player.Location = New Point((Player.Location.X - PSpeed), Player.Location.Y)

        End If

    End Sub

End Region


Region Enemy Behavior

    Private Sub EnemyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnemyTimer.Tick

        For Each PicBox2 In EnemyList
            If ((PicBox2.Left - ESpeed < 0) Or (PicBox2.Right + ESpeed >= Me.Width - 10)) Then
                'Something I don't really understand seems to be going with the .Right reading where either it doesn't line up with the form width, or the form width doesn't line up with the form's zsize while running. The -10 pixels seem to offset it.
                For Each PicBox3 As PictureBox In EnemyList
                    PicBox3.Location = New Point(PicBox3.Location.X, PicBox3.Location.Y + PicBox3.Height)
                    If PicBox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Player.Bounds) Then GameOver = True
                Next
            End If
        Next

        For Each PicBox2 In EnemyList
            If ((PicBox2.Left + EMovDir * ESpeed < 0) Or (PicBox2.Right + EMovDir * ESpeed >= Me.Width - 10)) Then
                EMovDir = EMovDir * -1
            End If
        Next

        For Each PicBox2 In EnemyList
            If Not ((PicBox2.Left + EMovDir * ESpeed < 0) Or (PicBox2.Right + EMovDir * ESpeed >= Me.Width - 10)) Then
                PicBox2.Location = New Point(PicBox2.Location.X + EMovDir * ESpeed, PicBox2.Location.Y)
                If PicBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Player.Bounds) Then GameOver = True
            End If
        Next

    End Sub


End Region

End Class
```

The tutorial I was following used arrays instead of a list, but I thought I would try to code this in such a way that adding or removing enemies wouldn't require me to edit the code and learn how to along the way. I've already tried fixing everything that occurred to me could be the cause, which is how I've arrived at the code above. I really appreciate any help you can give in fixing this, as well as any advice, Thanks! (and sorry for my english)

Edit: I hadn't thought to make sure, but just confirmed the more "Enemy" picture boxes the worse the issue gets.

Edit2: Weird as it might sound I checked if maybe the slower player movement was an optical illusion due to the background and/or the aliens point of reference also being in movement. That was not it either.

Edit3: Running a third timer at a 1000 millisecond interval and displaying the number of seconds since the timer was enabled while checking against the stopwatch in my phone revealed that it's not that the entire form is slowing down. The issue is replicated regardless of any image size mode, or any other picturebox and timer property .

Edit4: If I stretch the form window while it's running so that the aliens aren't in view, the Player moves normally.

Edit5: [Solved]  The issue only occurs if the form has a background image. I have absolutely no idea why .

It took me way too long to track down what was causing this bizarre issue, and it's bizarre properties.

Regardless, I would like to thank Idle_Mind and Hack_Slash for helping me improve my code and teaching me some cool new stuff.

Comment: Why do you have NESTED FOR LOOPS in the Timer code?  That nested for loop isn't necessary at all.  Just work directly with `PicBox2` from the outer loop and get rid of the inner loop...

Comment: Also, if you find that the game is over, there's no need to continue processing the rest of the loop, or the rest of the code in the Tick() event...just set your flag then immediately call `Exit Sub`.

Comment: Why are you looping over the same enemy list 3 times? Just use multiple if statements in one loop. That will give you a 3x performance boost.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thanks for the advice! I nested the loop because I wanted to check the if statement for every "Enemy" and if any were true run the inner loop for every "Enemy" as well. I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what the issue is, would you mind letting me know? Also, I didn't know about "Exit Sub ", I'll change the code right away! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HackSlash Thanks a lot for the advice, I didn't think the impact on performance would be so large. Could that be what's causing the main issue? That's what I did initially however each time the aliens reached the edge of the form they would grow apart a little and I found separating everything fixed that issue. Since I didn't think it would matter much I just went with that. I will try to fix it some other way, and I'll let you know if I manage to.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've got it written, EVERY time an enemy hits the left or right sides, all enemies will move down.  But doesn't that mean they could all move down multiple times?...once for each time an enemy has hit the edge, which could be multiple enemies if they are in a column?

See if something more like this performs better:

```
Private Sub EnemyTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnemyTimer.Tick
    Dim edgeWasHit = EnemyList.Any(Function(pb) (pb.Left - ESpeed < 0) OrElse (pb.Right + ESpeed >= Me.Width - 10))
    Dim reverseDirection = EnemyList.Any(Function(pb) (pb.Left + EMovDir * ESpeed < 0) OrElse (pb.Right + EMovDir * ESpeed >= Me.Width - 10))
    If reverseDirection Then
        EMovDir = EMovDir * -1
    End If

    For Each PicBox2 In EnemyList
        If edgeWasHit Then
            ' move it down
            PicBox2.Location = New Point(PicBox2.Location.X, PicBox2.Location.Y + PicBox2.Height))
        End If

        ' move left/right
        PicBox2.Location = New Point(PicBox2.Location.X + EMovDir * ESpeed, PicBox2.Location.Y)

        If PicBox2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Player.Bounds) Then
            GameOver = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Idle_Mind , this worked way better than anything I have tried!  I've looked up what I didn't understand in what you have written, but I still don't understand how does VB know what (pb) is ? Does (pb) assume the value of everything in the list like "PicBox2" in the for loop?  Also, even with your code the issue with the player's movement still occurs. Could it have something to do with New Point() ? I thought it was a performance issue due to my code's inefficiency, but it doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: You're exactly right.  Each PictureBox in the List gets passed to the function and is referenced with the "pb" variable.  If it encounters any PictureBox that satisfies that condition, it returns true, and also stops processing so the rest of the PBs are not evaluated.  If all PBs are evaluated and none match the criteria, then false is returned.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue with your player movement is...as that is not adequately described in your problem.  Give me more details about what is happening and I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for all the time you spared me, it was very kind of you. The issue only occurs if the form has a background image, though I have no idea why. I've edited the original question with the issue's weird behavior. Thank you for helping me improve my code and teaching me about Function() !